# PyWin32: detect "ready" before using SendKeys again?

Tags: winapi, pywin32, wsh, sendkeys, wscript.shell

I'm using the following code to send keystrokes to an application:

```
import win32com.client
import time
process_id = 2032 # I change this value if needed
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.AppActivate(process_id)
shell.SendKeys('^o')
time.sleep(.5)
# more input ...
```

The problem is: at some point everything goes downhill, meaning: the application is hanging (**unpredictable for how long and when!**) for whatever reason with unpleasant consequences. For example instead of clicking the "OK" button via the {ENTER} command, that keystroke does something else. After that all the keystrokes mess things up because they do not do what they were intended to do. Is there a difference between using time.sleep and win32api.sleep by the way? And is there a systematic way to check whether the application that I'm sending the keystrokes to, is in a stable ready-state again?

Comment: The functions of `time.sleep` and `win32api.sleep` are the same, except that `time.sleep` is in seconds and  `win32api.sleep` is in milliseconds.

Comment: Seems pointless to use sleep at all

Comment: @David: it does help. I can use a sleep delay which gives the program the time it needs to open a file or make edits or save a modified file. I've had scenarios where it completely breaks without the delays. But instead of guessing which delay can handle any circumstances, I would prefer a more systematic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is developed by you, you can use [`SendMessageTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagetimeouta) to check the response of the app window. If the response times out, the application is considered to be hang on(not on ready-state).

Comment: If the application was developed by me I would not need to send keystrokes to it ;-) I'm trying to execute a program thousands of times (once for every file) and the program doesn't have an API nor can it be executed via the command line.

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9ded354a-345c-48b1-ab07-c6814f8003fa/check-if-a-process-or-service-is-hangingnot-responding?forum=winserverpowershell) and [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.responding?view=netframework-4.8), does `Process.Responding` Property help?

Comment: Saw the last comment just now: looks like Process.Responding is not available in pywin32. I have searched for "responding" in the documentation but I only find 2 items which seem to be unrelated :-/

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to port my code to C#, so that I can test Process.Responding, but it doesn't look like in C# it is as simple as `shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")`

Comment: I think I found (part of) the answer. It looks like I'm using AppActivate too much. Using AppActivate shortly before SendKeys seems to mess things up (swallowing letters etc). So what I do now instead is to check whether my app still has focus. If it doesn't, I refocus and sleep for 2 seconds before sending keys (or calling AppActivate again in case focus got lost again during the sleep).